# Relative URI problems - designing WPF window in VS / Blend, but opening the window using a different c# environment

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, uri

Please excuse the newbie question - my background is Unix and I am very green when it comes to WPF...

**//Context//**
I need to design a single page WPF-based UI, using Visual Studio, or Blend.

Additionally, I need this to be portable outside the microsoft generated solution... this is because I need to be able to define the business logic within a different c# environment, that is exposed by software called 'NinjaTrader' (for those who may use it).

*I am restricted to .NET 3.5*

**//Additional info//**
Right now, I am trying to get to proof-of-concept as quickly as possible.  I have successfully implemented the UI using winforms. by simply designing the form within VS, and then copying the auto-generated designer code into my own abstract class definition (say 'myForm') within NinjaTrader.  I then have to inherit myForm into a new class definition within a 'standard' NinjaTrader.Indicator class (this is necessary to be able to instantiate the myForm2 class), and by passing the outer class to the constructor of myForm2, and overriding the methods I need for the business logic, I can display a UI upon 'OnStartUp' of the NinjaTrader.Indicator class, and implement the behaviour that I need.

**//My problem//**
WPF is proving more difficult so far.  I have tried copying the class definitions from 'WPFWindow.xaml.cs', and also what is necessary from 'WPFWindow.g.cs' into a single .cs file (due to limitations within NinjaTrader, I must use a single file for this), and then instantiating this class from another NinjaTrader.Indicator class.

Everything is in the same namespace, though I am repeatedly stumped when it comes to the relative Uri and it seems I get the following message, no matter what I do:

> Cannot locate resource 'wpfwindow/wpfwindow.xaml'

Now - I am aware that the relative Uri will not be the same, when running from within a different application, and I have even tried copying the WPFWindow.xaml file to a new folder (*within* what seems to be the current working directory, and *without* any spaces) and calculating the relative  :

```
    string cpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string installPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\NinjaTrader 7\bin64\WPFWindow\WPFWindow.xaml";
    Uri cwUri = new Uri(@cpath);
    Uri instUri = new Uri(@installPath);
    string relPath = cwUri.MakeRelativeUri(instUri).ToString();

    System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri(relPath, System.UriKind.Relative);

    System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
```

However, I am still getting the same error.

I would be extremely grateful if anyone has any advice / suggestions as to how I might try to proceed.

Is there another way that I can load an XAML file (that is external to the current application / project), *without* using a relative Uri in order to display a single UI window?  Any advice on what the bare minimum (less is definitely more reliable in this case) I would need to implement in order to do this and define the business logic, would be extremely helpful...

Thanks in advance for any advice

J

EDIT: (& Reponse to Brian S):

Thanks for the response, and also for the reccomendation on material.  It is entirely possible that I have misunderstood the necessary architecture involved with WPF...

Therefore, please let me know it that is the case...  My understanding is as follows:

The graphical composition, content, layout, etc is *all* specified within the XAML file.  Behaviour, interaction, event handling etc is specified in the code-behind.

Once the XAML markup has been written, I had made the assumption that, in order to instantiate the window I had designed, all I needed to do was to load / parse it into a tree of objects within - lets say - a class that inherits System.Windows.Window, and is named as the same class as in x:class="myClass", within the XAML file.

Upon re-reading what I wrote previously, I realise that I was not all that clear about the situation.  I can use multiple files for the solution, without a problem, the issue arises as follows:

With classes that are partial, across 2 files - lets say file1.cs and file2.cs, class methods will only be recognized within the same file that they are defined (unless I actually instantiate the class - after which I can call it's methods).   So - for example - I could not specify InitializeComponent() in file1.cs, and then define a constructor in file2 that refers to InitializeComponent()...  I hope that makes sense...

What I can do, which seems to work, is to avoid defining methods outside of the file that I need to reference them in.  And thus, avoiding the use of partial classes as far as possible.

I can define a class in one file (say class1.cs), then instantiate it from another file (say class2.cs) no problem, by using:

```
private class1 mynewclass1 = new class1(args)
```

I can also use:

```
'System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(args);'
```

Though I seem to be running into issues with the relative addressing, as no matter what I try it does not seem to find the .xaml file..

Is there a way that I can try to load the xaml file without using relative addressing?  I have been looking at XamlReader, though I'm not sure it can do what I need....

Thanks again,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow, you're trying to treat the WpfWindow.xaml file as a loose resource file located in the same directory.  This is not how WPF works - the WpfWindow.xaml file is a partial class with the codebehind.  This is possible with XAML Resource Dictionaries, but I don't believe it is possible with the WpfWindow.xaml file because they need to be compiled together.

If you want a single-file solution, it is a lot more work, but everything you do in XAML, you can do through code.  So you can create a window, add controls, position them and connect behaviors all through the codebehind.  Obviously, this is not the ideal approach, but it sounds like you've got some pretty significant limitations (I'm not familiar with NinjaTrader).

The MSDN Documentation will provide help on the code necessary to manually construct and layout a WPF window, or if you are looking for another resource, [Applications = Code + Markup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619573), by Charles Petzold goes through doing anything you need to do with WPF from codebehind.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and also for the reccomendation on material.  It is entirely possible that I have misunderstood the necessary architecture involved with WPF...

Therefore, please let me know it that is the case...  My understanding is as follows:

The graphical composition, content, layout, etc is _all_ specified within the XAML file.  Behaviour, interaction, event handling etc is specified in the code-behind.

Comment: @ Brian S - I am not allowed enough characters here to provide you with a proper response.  Therefore, I will add an edit to the bottom of the original post

Comment: I've since decided to take an easier route, for now, and design a complete application in WPF, and interface between the two using netnamedpipes in WCF.  I hope that the latency will be negligible. Thanks.  J